# How to identify the newly added disk in virtual linux(RHEL 7 &6) host using ansible yaml code

Tags: ansible

i am planing to write ansible playbook for file system creation. i am using Logical volume manager(LVM).
can any one help me to identify the new lun using ansible modules.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, this is very operating system specific.  Your best path forward is to figure out what steps you would do from the command line to detect that there is a new disk and then use `shell`, parsing the result stdout.  For example, on ubuntu, you might run `fdisk -l` and look for unpartitioned / unallocated drives and parse the output.